# Unexpected behaviour of 'every' gnuplot keyword inside 'do for' loop

Tags: gnuplot

Unexpected behaviour of `'every'` inside `'do for'` loop compared to its behaviour outside the loop

```
set style line 1 linecolor rgb "blue" pointtype 7 pointsize 3 lt 1
#plot 4 points
plot 'every_test.txt' every 1:1:0:0:3:0 u 1:2 with points linestyle 1 
# Next 4 lines, when active, draw 2 arrows from 2nd point to 1st & 3rd 
#pause 1
#replot '' every 1:1:1:0:1:0 u 3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head linestyle 1
#pause 1
#replot '' every 1:1:2:0:2:0 u 3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head linestyle 1
# Try 'do for' loop instead of preceding 4 line to draw the 2 arrows
do for [k = 1:2] {
   pause 1
   replot '' every 1:1:k:0:k:0 u 3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head linestyle 1
}
# Loop behaves unexpectedly. 
# It draws 1st arrow, removes it [how does replot even do that!] 
# then draws 2nd arrow. Final result is 2nd arrow only. 
replot '' every 1:1:1:0:1:0 u 3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head linestyle 1
# Line above attempts to restore 1st arrow, but only results in error:
# "undefined variable: k" even though it makes no reference to k.
```

Data in 'every_test.txt:

```
1  2 
2  3 1.9  2.9 -0.8 -0.8
3  2 2.1  2.9  0.8 -0.8
4  1

5  3
6  4
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is your use of "replot".
Proposed version with a loop but no "replot"

```
do for [k=1:N] {
    plot 'every_test.txt' every 1:1:0:0:3:0 u 1:2 with points linestyle 1, \
    '' every 1:1:1:0:k:0 u 3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head linestyle 1
    pause 1
}
```

Comment: I was unhelpfully vague. When the loop is replaced by two calls of replot, I get the desired output. First call has 'every 1:1:1:0:1:0' and 2nd call has 'every 1:1:2:0:2:0'. The loop has 'every 1:1:k:0:k:0' for k=1,2. Hence the loop should logically produce the same output but it does not. I need the loop because the true dataset is long.

Comment: Please show your full script.   In the fragment shown above "replot" makes no sense.

Comment: Have replaced snippet with full script

Comment: As I said, you do NOT want "replot" inside a loop for this.   Each "replot" re-executes the previous plot command and adds new stuff.  In the second time through the loop k=2 and the full command being executed is `   plot 'every_test.dat' every 1:1:0:0:3:0 u 1:2 with points linestyle 1, '' every 1:1:k:0:k:0 u 3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head linestyle 1, '' every 1:1:k:0:k:0 u 3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head linestyle 1`.  The first clause came from your original plot, the second was added by the first loop iteration and the third was added by the second loop iteration.  [continued]

Comment: [continued] Both the 2nd and 3rd clauses refer to k and k is currently 2 so they both plot the same thing.     The loop can be replaced by a single plot command `replot '' every 1:1:kmin:0:kmax with vectors`

Comment: Loop is OK. Just don't put a replot in it. See revised answer.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Subtle. I had not fully appreciated the behaviour of replot. Thank you! That said, the limitation of replacing the loop with "replot ' ' every 1:1:kmin:0:kmax" is that I lose the pause after plotting each vector. The pause is essential to visualise sequential growth of vector connections between points in "tunable" slow motion. Can the pause be reinstated in your suggested remedy?

Comment: Just edited the script as per suggestion. Works a treat! Thank you very much once more!